# Get a list of files in a revision with JGit

Tags: java, jgit

Does anyone know how to use JGit API to get a list of files? I try to find a similar function like using the `git show` command on a local repository such as

```
    git ls-tree -r --name-only 7feff221f86e040f0cd2e4227e9e1496fe16f376
```

I have some code like that

```
    File gitDir = new File("/Users/xiansongzeng/NIOServer");
    Git git = Git.open(gitDir);
    Repository repo = git.getRepository();

    ObjectId lastCommitId = repo.resolve("7feff221f86e040f0cd2e4227e9e1496fe16f376");
    RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repo);
    RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(lastCommitId);
    RevTree tree= commit.getTree();
    TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repo);
    treeWalk.addTree(tree);
    treeWalk.setRecursive(true);

    treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create("src/main/java/nds/socket/server/Reader.java"));
    if(!treeWalk.next()){
        System.out.println("Not found.");
        return;
    }
    ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
```

This code targets at a local repository, uses `RevWalk` to walk the revision tree of the last commit. I find this example using `PathFilter` to get the reference of a file, but dunno how to get the list of all Java files. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I actually check treeWalk.next() and use treeWalk.getPathString(), can get a list of all files, should I just compare the long string containing ".java" or use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tree filter like `PathSuffixFilter.create(".java")` is recommended over testing the path returned from `getPathString`.

The reason for this is that `getPathString` has to decode the path (which is a `byte[]` internally), while `PathSuffixFilter` works directly on the `byte[]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a nicer method. I am reading too many APIs these few weeks and feel dizzy. This one is the most complex.

Comment: Yes, the API is powerful but can be complex. Do you have any suggestions for improving it, or where to add more documentation?

Comment: I am a fresher using git api, I find it hard to use because there are few tutorials on line and some of them using the deprecated api. I like the way in which Google javaparser project implement.It separates interface and abstract classes to tell the intention of every class and package clearly.

Comment: I also think that jgit is powerful, but the api has room for improvement, what is the best place to discuss possible changes?

Comment: @centic See [here](http://eclipse.org/jgit/support/), either write to the mailing list or file a new enhancement in Bugzilla. Proposals for radical changes will probably be rejected as we don't want to force existing users to change their code. But I think ideas for improvements or additions, or patches for documentation, are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**ls-tree** is implemented in JGit: [`org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/src/org/eclipse/jgit/pgm/LsTree.java`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit.pgm/src/org/eclipse/jgit/pgm/LsTree.java)
Usage is

`jgit ls-tree [-r|--recursive] <tree-ish> [-- paths...]`

And cat-file is simple ([credit goes to Shawn Pearce at git-dev@eclipse.org mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jgit-dev/msg00558.html))

```
  int type;
  if (argv[0].equals("blob"))
    type = Constants.OBJ_BLOB;
  ...

  ObjectId id = ObjectId.fromString(argv[1]);
  ObjectLoader ldr = db.open(id, type);
  byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
  InputStream in = ldr.openInputStream();
  int n;
  while ((n = in.read(tmp)) > 0)
    System.out.write(tmp, 0, n);
  in.close();
```